# Ruby on Rails routes: Multiple namespaces and multiple domains: best practice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, namespaces

I have a Ruby on Rails instance that powers at least 4 different websites, more to be added in the future. The websites fall under 3 categories:

- Admin Portal (intranet)
- Public pages (landing pages etc.)
- Browser version of app

I've set up namespaces for these (admin/, public/ and my/) and this works great in my development environment (e.g., localhost:3000/admin). However in production each of these sites will run on a different domain/subdomain.

For example:

- Admin portal on admin.domain.com (admin namespace)
- Landing page on otherdomain.com (public namespace)
- Questionnaire on survey.otherdomain.com (public namespace)
- App on my.domain.com (my namespace)

I **do not** want the namespace to appear as a URI segment in the URL, and it should also not be required in the subdomain. I want to route each domain to its appropriate namespace.

The main reason I want to split the namespaces this way is that the Admin and App both use a very specific set of resources that will not be required for all other (public) websites, and I want to keep the development workflow separate and the code decoupled between these areas.

What is the best way to set up this kind of routing?

PS: I am running this with Webrick in development, and with nginx/passsenger in production. I hope I don't need to do anything drastic with nginx to get this working.

Answer (score 2):

All your work should be done in nginx config file.

For example, for admin.domain.com

```
server {
listen       80; #or 443 if you use ssl
server_name  admin.domain.com;
root /usr/local/app/;

#ssl_certificate      app.cert; 
#ssl_certificate_key  app.key;

location  ~ ^/admin.domain.com(/.*|$) {
passenger_base_uri /;   #change this if you want a base uri
passenger_app_root  /usr/local/app/;
passenger_document_root  /usr/local/app/public;
passenger_enabled on;
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, do I also need to set up domain-based constraints in my config/routes.rb file?

Comment: No, you don't . The "passenger_base_uri" is where to change. For example:  " admin.domain.com/profile ", with setting "passenger_base_uri /admin.domain.com;"  then this equals to "localhost:3000/profile".

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a go and accept your answer if it works. +1 for being so helpful :)

Comment: I'm not having any luck with this setting (passenger_base_uri). The documentation states:

"Used to specify that the given URI is an distinct application that should be served by Passenger."

I don't want to serve different apps. I have a single rails app, with multiple domains pointing to it, and for each domain I want to use a different namespace in my routes.